# Google Analytics share custom report data

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up simple report (flat table). Now I need to share it with the client, so he is able to see fresh data. What is the best approach? Create a custom view?

Answer (score 1):

You can export your custom report like this:

[image]

and then select "PDF" (to send it as a PDF).

You can set up a schedule report to be emailed out at a desired frequency: once, daily, weekly, monthly, etc. Alternatively, you can provide read-only access (at the VIEW level) for your client so that they can go into the reports whenever they want, but they won't be able to do anything).

Comment: Yes I know about this option. But this way I would need to export it every day right? Is there a way to make the report accessible to the client?